# How to iterate 2arraylist and exit when first matching element is found in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 2 array list with some common values in both.

I tried for loop, do while loop but nothing is working for me

I want the very first matching/common element and return the same and exit the code there itself

```
boolean good = true; 
for (int i = 0; i <1Val.size(); i ++) { 
   if (!(2Val.contains(1Val.get(i)))) { 
      System.out.println("Matched---" +quoteVal.get(i)); 
      good = false; break; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: SInce I was not able to post the code which i tried in main desc.. posting here 
  `boolean good = true; 
for (int i = 0; i <1Val.size(); i ++) { 
    if(!(2Val.contains(1Val.get(i)))) { 
        System.out.println("Matched---" +1Val.get(i)); 
        good = false; 
        break; 
    } 
}`

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code there.

Comment: In this code, the first element that doesn't have a match is printed. If you want the first element, then remove ```!``` from the check.

Comment: Oh, thanks Michael Bianconi.. it is working .. thanks a lot .

Comment: Can you please suggest how to return that value?

Comment: @Dolly replace your break with return 1Val.get(i) ... but your code won't compile, variable names are not allowed to start with a number

Answer (score 1):

You can just use Java Streams to solve this:

```
boolean good = val1.stream().anyMatch(val2::contains);
```

If you need the value of the first match you can use this:

```
Optional<String> firstMatch = val1.stream()
        .filter(val2::contains)
        .findFirst();
```

Use `Optional.isPresent()` to check if a match is found and `Optional.get()` to get the actual value.

To improve the performance for large lists use a set for `val2`. It has *O(1)* time complexity for `Set.contains()`.

Answer (score 0):

If one of the array lists is smaller than you should use that particular one's size in a for loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1Val.size(); i++){

      if(2val.contains(1Val.get(i))){
         return true; // common value found
      }

}
return false; // common value not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
for (int i=0;i<arrayList2.size();i++) {

for (int j=0;j<arrayList1.size(); j++) {


if(al2.get(i)equals(al1.get(j))){
// do something// you can add them to the new arraylist to process further or type break; to break from the loop
{
} 
}
```

Comment: you have to use equals instead of ==

Comment: Yes, sorry, you are right i forgot i was using arrayList and not arrays

Answer (score 0):

maybe you would like to use streams

```
    List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d","e");
    List<String> list2 =  Arrays.asList("b","e");

    //gets the list of common elments
    List<String> common = list1.stream().filter(s -> list2.contains(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (common.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("no common elements");
    }else {
        System.out.println("common elements");
        common.forEach(System.out::println);
    }


    //just the check if any equal elements exist
    boolean commonElementsExist = list1.stream().anyMatch(s -> list2.contains(s));


    //3rd version get the first common element
    Optional<String> firstCommonElement = list1.stream().filter(s -> list2.contains(s)).findFirst();

    if(firstCommonElement.isPresent()) {
        System.out.println("the first common element is "+firstCommonElement.get());
    }else {
        System.out.println("no common elements");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `labeled` statement for this

```
outer_loop:
for (int i=0;i<arrayList2.size();i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<arrayList1.size(); j++) {
        if(arrayList2.get(i)==arrayList1.get(j)){
            break outer_loop; 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: if you use == it won't work, you have to use equals
btw. using a label for this purpose is very ... ugly